# Angular ui-router - expose a portion of the layout to a child state/template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Taking the following mockup screenshot as an example, I need to be able to put some custom actions on the top right of the view. What the user sees there will depend on the current view that's being displayed (e.g. share button).

I'm using `ui-router`, and nested states. I may be approaching it wrong, so my question is more generic than specific. What is the best way to go about exposing a portion of the layout to a child `state` that may be a few layers deep?

```
<div>
   <header id="menu">
      <a class="fa fa-bars"></a>

      <div>Title</div>

      <div class="actions">
         <!-- I want a child state, possibly multiple levels deep in the 
              state hierarchy, to be able to insert content here -->
      </div>
   </header>

   <div id="content">
      <div ui-view></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: mockup]

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of approaches, pick one that feels the best to you:

1) The `actions` view could be implemented as a directive that watches `$state.current` and based on the current state, update its view accordingly. If you want the ability for each individual state to specify their own actions, then perhaps setting the `data` property when using `$stateProvider.state`, and using that information to determine what actions there are could work.

2) Implement some kind of cross transclude directive. So something like this (untested and not fully implemented, be sure to test for memory leaks):

```
angular.module('app',[]).directive('crossTransclude', function(){
    return {
        require : '^crossTranscludeController',
        transclude: true,
        link: function($scope, $el, $attr, ctrl, transclude){
            ctrl.setTranscludeFn(transclude);
            $scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
              ctrl.unsetTranscludeFn(transclude);
            });
        }
    };
})
.directive('crossTranscludeController', function(){
  return {
    controller : function CrossTranscludeController(){
      this.transcludeFn = null;
      this.transcludeTargetEl = null;
      this.setTranscludeFn = function(func){
        this.transcludeFn = func;
        this._crossTransclude();
      }

      this.unsetTranscludeFn = function(){
        this.transcludeFn = null;
        this._crossTransclude();
      }

      this.registerTranscludeTarget = function($element){
        this.transcludeTargetEl = $element;
        this._crossTransclude();
      }

      this.deregisterTranscludeTarget = function(){
        this.transcludeTargetEl = null;
        this._crossTransclude();
      }

      this._crossTransclude = function(){
        if(this.transcludedClone)
        if(this.transcludeFn && this.transcludeTargetEl){
          this.transcludeFn(function(clone){
            this.transcludeTargetEl.empty();
            this.transcludeTargetEl.append(clone);
          });
        } else {
          if(this.transcludeTargetEl){
            this.transcludeTargetEl.empty();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
})
.directive('crossTranscludeTarget', function(){
  return {
    require: '^crossTranscludeController',
    link: function($scope, $el, $attr, ctrl){
      ctrl.registerTranscludeTarget($el);
      $scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
        ctrl.deregisterTranscludeTarget();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Which is used like:

index.html

```
<div cross-transclude-controller>
    <div cross-transclude-target>

    </div>


    <div ui-view>

    </div>
</div>
```

subview.html

```
<div>
    <div cross-transclude>
        This content should end up in 'cross-transclude-target', bound to the subview's scope
    </div>
</div>
```